# How display content created by specific user using ASP.NET Core, Identity Framework with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to create an ASP.NET Core web application where people can create, edit, delete, and view goals. I was able to use Entity Framework with Identity Framework to authenticate users but I want to authorize/display content specifically recorded by that user. Right now, the page will display everything created by all users.

This is the index method in the `Goals` controller.

```
[Authorize]
// GET: Goals
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Goal.ToListAsync());
}
```

Here is some `Goals` controller code that pulls in `UserManager`:

```
public class GoalsController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public GoalsController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
```

I have read a few different approaches with regular old Asp.Net but nothing the says what the best practice is for ASP.NET Core. Should I be using a `LINQ`?

Here is the goal model:

```
public class Goal
{
    [Key]
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsSubGoal { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Due Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]

    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Created On")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Modified")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]

    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
}
```

`UserID` is where the user id is being stored at the time a goal is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a filter in you LINQ Query like this:

```
[Authorize]
// GET: Goals
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    // the instruction below this comment will help to get the Id of the current authenticated user. 
    // Make sure you derive your controller from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(HttpContext.User);
    return View(await _context.Goal.Where(g => g.UserID == userId).ToListAsync());
}
```

Comment: I actually found a pretty darn good Microsoft article about this which is probably more complete since it has each part of CRUD and also how to set up authorization handlers for different user roles:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data